# Cannot fix ITMS-90738 and ITMS-90683 issues with NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription (Core Location on iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, core-location

I need help because I have not succeeded to fix the following issues:

**ITMS-90738**: Invalid purpose string value - The “NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription” value for the NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription key isn’t allowed in “SuperNewsV2UIKit.app”. Your app’s code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data, or the app has one or more entitlements that permit such access. The Info.plist file for the “SuperNewsV2UIKit.app” bundle should contain a NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/requesting_access_to_protected_resources.
**ITMS-90683**: Missing purpose string in Info.plist - Your app’s code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data, or the app has one or more entitlements that permit such access. The Info.plist file for the “SuperNewsV2UIKit.app” bundle should contain a NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. If you’re using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/requesting_access_to_protected_resources.
There is actually what I have done and I don't understand yet why the issue is not fixed after uploading on App Store Connect:

Main info.plist:
[image]

Info.plist (disabled):
[image]

Localizables for Info.plist, I use the new String Catalog (`InfoPlist.xcstrings`):
[image]

Note: NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription is needed on localizables, even after replacing with NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription, my location feature on map won't work, even for asking user permission.

Can you help me please to fix this issue ? Documentation has not helped me to fix the issue after applying the recommendations.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to use the recommended keys, but it failed be valid after uploading the build on App Store Connect. Also, after replacing `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` 
key by `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`, location function don't work even for asking permission, I need to add on my string catalog the content for `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in order to use location functions.

Comment: You description has to be meaningful, tell the user why you need their location

Comment: @loremipsum, I gave the purpose on localizables on InfoPlist.xcstrings. This is my description: In order to use the world map with best experience and suggestion, allow the app the access of location service to place you on the map and suggest you the country to center on the map.

Comment: Rename maybe the translation key?